# Magento could not save static block with store id

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have been created a custom module to make importing static block from my CSV

The code below:

```
$staticblock = Mage::getModel('cms/block');
$staticblock->load($identifier)->getData();
$staticblock->setData('title', $title);
$staticblock->setData('identifier', $identifier);
$staticblock->setData('content', $content);
$staticblock->setData('creation_time', $creation_time);
$staticblock->setData('update_time', $update_time);
$staticblock->setData('is_active', $is_active);
$staticblock->setData('stores',$store_id);
```

if the static block  is already with my store id, the error showing in my report file

```js
"a:5:{i:0;s:84:"A block identifier with the same properties already exists in the selected store.bug";i:1;s:1117:"#0 "
```

My code work well if the block with identifier is not ready, it will be created a new static block.

Comment: First just check if that block is already there for your specific store?

Answer (score 0):

```
$staticblock = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($identifier);
if ((!$staticblock) || (!$staticblock->getId())) {  //not exists , or try using  $staticblock->isObjectNew()
    $staticblock->setData('identifier', $identifier);
}
$staticblock->setData('title', $title);
$staticblock->setData('content', $content);
$staticblock->setData('creation_time', $creation_time);
$staticblock->setData('update_time', $update_time);
$staticblock->setData('is_active', $is_active);
$staticblock->setData('stores',$store_id);
```

Try to see whether it is new object.